# Renewal of residence and work permit in Spain

Tags: visa, working-visas, spain

I have a work visa in Spain for 3 years, which is about to expire. On my TIE, it says "RESIDENCIA Y TRABAJO". I would like to know the procedure to renew it. My employer is happy to extend my contract, but they are not sure about the procedure. Should my employer give me a new contract first? Can they give me a work contract without a validity for my NIE? Can any one explain the procedure?

P.S I am from India.